# Что подавать в качестве параметров (sender,e) в процедуру события C++?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio

Есть событие, например:

```
private: System::Void button1_click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{ // код события; }
```

Как вызвать его программно, т.е. где нибудь в коде? Что нужно подавать в качестве `Sender` и `e` в процедуру `button1_click(sender, e)`.

`sender` я предполагаю, можно `NULL`, а вот `e` не знаю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте соответствующий метод объекта, являющегося источником события. Для кнопки Windows Forms это [Button::PerformClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx)

```
button->PerformClick();
```

Вообще sender - это экземпляр класса, являющегося источником события, а e - это экземпляр вспомогательного класса, предназначенного для передачи дополнительной информации в событии.